# Image of open unit disc $\{z \in \mathbb C~:~|z|<1\}$ under the map $w=\frac{1}{(z+i)^2}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

How to find the image of open unit disc $\{z \in \mathbb C~:~|z|<1\}$ under the map $w=\frac{1}{(z+i)^2}$.

Clearly the transformation $w$ is a composition of a translation, an inversion and a squaring, I could not connect the image set under inversion here. How to determine the inversion of points of the polar form $w_1=i+re^{i\theta}, r<1$?

Comment: It's easy to see where the unit circle is mapped to - either directly, or noting that $1/(z+i)$ maps to a half plane (so the unit circle maps to a line) and the squaring bends it and stretches it

Comment: I think $\frac{1}{z+i}$ maps the unit circle onto the line $w=u-\frac{i}{2},~u \in \mathbb R$, right?

Comment: True - need to see two finite images eg at $i,1$ say to conclude as by general theory the image of a circle under a Mobius transform is a circle or line and $-i$ goes to infinity so we get a line and that is determined by two finite points

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: multiplying $\,w=\frac{1}{(z+i)^2}\,$ by its conjugate $\,\bar w=\frac{1}{(\bar z - i)^2}\,$:

$$
|w|^2=\frac{1}{\left(|z|^2-i(z-\bar z)+1\right)^2} \gt \frac{1}{4\left(1 + \text{Im}(z)\right)^2} \gt \frac{1}{16}
$$